# Which cable to use for Antenna?

Tags: cables, tv-antenna

I have purchased an outdoor antenna. I need to run a line between the antenna and the TV. To save time, i'd like to use the existing (unused) cable line by attaching the antenna to one of the cables in the image. Can someone with experience please advise which of these cables go to where and which one I can safely connect my antenna to that will track to my TV.
We currently only have Centurylink via a phone line (the small brownish cable attached to the PVC pipe on the left of the image).

[image: cable]

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you have a common RF 4 way cable splitter, with cable coming into through the green wire and 4 TVs (the other cables). You should look at the splitter closely (is this RF or digital; one in and four out?), and determine if I traced the line correctly.

If this looks like an RF 4 way splitter, and you want to add an antenna (no more "cable TV") you just need to remove the green cable from the splitter and plug in the antenna.

However, if you have a digital (only) splitter, it will not allow the antenna signal to pass through. If you can't be sure what kind of splitter you have, then just try it... nothing will explode if I'm wrong.

[image]

If you only have two wires from the antenna, then you need a converter like this:

[image]

Comment: Thanks Ben. Yep, you did trace the line correctly... I do have a digital splitter, so I guess I need to connect the antenna to each of the 4 cables and see which one works on the TV...

Comment: @AndrewFindlay well, if you only have one TV, then yes. You don't need a splitter. Use the single port coaxial connector (also called a ground block) located about 6-8 inches above, and to the right of the splitter to make your (single) connection. Disconnect the green wire(s) and plug the antenna cable into one side. Then just try each of the other four cables (each one probably goes to a separate room). But if I misunderstood, and you do want to connect four TVs then the easiest thing to do would be to get a four way RF (radio frequency) splitter, and transfer all the cables to it.

Comment: @AndrewFindlay I would at least try hooking the antenna to the splitter first. Like I said, it won't hurt anything.

Comment: If memory serves, TV antennas are 300 Ohm the cable is 50 Ohm. you will need a adapter to go the the antenna that matches the impedance (ohms). Splitter's have line loss so it may be best to go direct and not use a splitter unless you have a strong signal.

Comment: @EdBeal I thought he already had a cable from the antenna (but now I don't know). I edited my post with a pic of what I'm thinking you mean by 300 ohm adapter.

Comment: @AndrewFindlay If you have a coaxial cable from the antenna, it could be 75 or 50 ohms. Cable is typically 50 ohms and satellite is typically 75 ohms. Making mismatched connections to or from a 50 and 75 ohm cables results in about 5% signal loss.

Comment: I did double check and may be showing my age the flat ribbon cable that used to supply the signal from antennas was 300 Ohm in the days before 1/4 wave antennas as that was the characteristic impedance. You are correct on the type of adapters I was thinking about to match the signal. +